# How to confirm MS Office is getting updates

Tags: windows-10, freeze, windows-update, microsoft-office-2016

I have been having stability issues with Office apps, such as random hanging and freezing, and I noticed a lot of updates address such problems. Is there a way I can verify the Office has been successfully installing updates or can I force a manual update? I am suspicious because I used the [OffCat tool](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2812744/office-configuration-analyzer-tool-offcat-information) and it said some updates were missing. I tried following instructions [such as this one](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Install-Office-updates-2AB296F3-7F03-43A2-8E50-46DE917611C5), but there is no button "Update Options".

[image: offcat screenshot]

I have reinstalled the OS several times and tried repairing the Office installation with no success. Right now Word can't start and the only program I had opened since turning on the computer was Firefox.

Funny enough sometimes the OffCAT tool freezes. This problem has been going on for a while, any suggestions on any other forums or contacts to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your screenshot does not indicate that you have updates missing. Here is a screenshot of OffCAT that is reporting missing updates:
[image: https://imgur.com/a/w6UE0]

However, here is how you can verify it:

### For Click-to-Run versions

You can verify this using the Microsoft Office version number.

To get Microsoft Office 2016 version number:

1. Open a Microsoft Office app, e.g. Microsoft Excel
2. Go to backstage view (Click on the "File" button)
3. Go to "Account"
4. Click on the About Excel button
5. Read the version number from top
6. Compare the version number with the one in [Office 365 client update channel releases](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/office/mt465751)

### For MSI versions

As I understand, not only you wish to verify if there is updates, you want to install them too! So, let's do it all in one go.

1. Ensure that Microsoft Update service is enabled

   1. Open Settings app
   2. Click on "Update & Security"
   3. In the right pane, click on "Advanced options"
   4. Make sure the following check box is checked:

      Give me updates for other Microsoft products when I update Windows
2. Run Windows Update

   1. Open Settings app
   2. Click on "Update & Security"
   3. Click on "Check for updates"

Comment: First question, how do I know if I'm using Click-to-Run or MSI version (what is the difference)?

Comment: See this: http://windowsitpro.com/microsoft-office/determining-if-office-installation-click-run-or-not

Comment: It would appear that I'm using MSI version. I have checked off "give me updates for other MS products" but I notice it often doesn't work properly. You don't really say how to check that it is working properly, only how to do it?

Comment: You say "I notice it often doesn't work properly". How do you know that when you have unchecked this option?

Comment: I clarify, the option to download additional MS updates is checked on. Why do I think it's not working? See the screen shot of OffCAT above. Also because there are problems, such as freezing, which should have been fixed by updates.

Comment: What I see in your screenshot is that 9 updates are successfully installed.

Comment: Maybe I'm misreading it but they are categorized as "issues" so I thought that meant they were not installed correctly. The question still stands though, how can it be confirmed that updates are properly being installed for Office 2016?

Comment: Here is an example of an OffCAT scan that indicates the updates are missing: http://imgur.com/a/w6UE0. The problem seems to be that you have convinced yourself that you have missing updates and do not trust anything or anyone that tells you otherwise.